# Sum of the determinants of the principal minors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What does the sum of the determinants of the principal minors indicate an $n \times n$ matrix and what is its relation to the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: What do you mean by principal minors?  The top left $k\times k$ minors?

Comment: @Mick [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Other_applications) says it's all the minors where you choose the same rows as columns. Which would make more sense, since the top left minors (which Wiki calls "leading principal minors") is way too coordinate dependent to have any fundamental connection to the characteristic polynomial. But we need to wait for confirmation.

Comment: Assuming I am right about what "principal minors" means (and even if I'm not), have you actually tried it with, say, a $2\times 2$ example? What is the characteristic polynomial of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$? What are its principal minors? One connection between these two is quite obvious once you just write it down and look at it. All that's left is proving that it is true for bigger matrices as well.

Comment: It is true. Check out the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0021904516300533

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that
$$ \det(xI-A) = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k} \sum_{I\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}\\|I|=k} \det A_I \cdot x^{n-k}$$
where the matrix $A_I$ is a submatrix of $A$ s.t. $$A_I = (a_{ij})_{i,j\in I},$$
if $ I = \emptyset$ then $A_I:=1$.